# how to know my vungle ad is completely seen by user or not?

Tags: android, vungle-ads

I am using a vungle app-id in my app and I want to increment the wallet of the user, only if the video ad is completely seen by user.

//code in my  Activity

```
  final VunglePub vunglePub = VunglePub.getInstance();
        final String app_id= "58d46c1feba9a90a1a000011"; //vungleid
        vunglePub.init(this,app_id);
        final EventListener vungleListener= new EventListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onAdEnd(boolean b, boolean b1) {
                Update();
            }
};
```

I am trying to update the wallet of user by calling Update method from onAdEnd method of listener but it updates the wallet even if the user closes the ad.

I am trying vungle for the first time, also searched a lot but didnt got my answer. Any help regarding this is appreciated. Thanks!..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am Gabor, working as Intergation Engineer @Vungle.

You can check our documentation here to see how you can use the event listeners.
https://support.vungle.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463100-Advanced-Settings-for-Vungle-Android-SDK

The above recommended onVideoView() was depricated, and you should use

```
@Override
    public void onAdEnd(boolean wasSuccessfulView, boolean wasCallToActionClicked) {
        // Called when the user leaves the ad and control is returned to your application        
        // if wasSuccessfulView is true, the user watched the ad and should be rewarded        
        // (if this was a rewarded ad).
        // if wasCallToActionClicked is true, the user clicked the call to action
        // button in the ad.
    }
```

If the ad completely by the user, the wasSuccessfulView boolean will be true.

If you have more question feel free to contact us at tech-support@vungle.com and we will help you out.

Gabor

Comment: please answer to my question, thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166986/how-to-close-finish-my-vungle-rewrded-video-ad-programatically-as-if-user-close

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    VunglePub vunglePub = VunglePub.getInstance();
    vunglePub.setEventListeners(vungleEventListener);
```

**Event Listner**

```
private final EventListener vungleEventListener = new EventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onVideoView(boolean arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        if (arg0) {
            addHint(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.videoHints));
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "5 Hints added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Watch Complete video to add hints", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdUnavailable(final String arg0) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(context, arg0, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onAdStart() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAdEnd(boolean arg0) {
        initialiseVungle();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdPlayableChanged(boolean arg0) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "You cannot play any ad now. Try after sometime", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
```